# N.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm brand new to react, and I'm trying to read an inline JSON object and display that data as a list of results

```
import SearchPage from './views/SearchPage'

function App() {
    const horseDataJSON = window.horseData;
    const [horses, setHorses] = useState(horseDataJSON);
    console.log(horseDataJSON);

    return (
        <div className='app'>
            {horses &&  <SearchPage horses={horses} />}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

However I am receiving the error `TypeError: N.map is not a function`. I have seen several solutions here using `.map()`, which leads me to think I'd do something like this

```
{horses &&
    horses.map((horse) =>
    <SearchPage horses={horses} />
    ))
}
```

But that just seems wrong given that my SearchPage component is going to be a list of horses, so using "horse" isn't going to work.

Terrible explanation of problem, but I am unfamiliar with React terminology. What is the correct way to integrate "map" into the above to resolve this error?

Example of horse.json as requested

```
[
    {
        "id": 75222685,
        "name": "Mellby Glader*",
        "link": "https://lardev-16953.bolt91.servebolt.com/product/wc-donation-mellby-glader/",
        "total_donation_amount": 0,
        "max_amount": "30000",
        "dontation_ended": false
    },
]
```

Comment: Is it an array?

Comment: Something is wrong with your horseDataJson check if it’s actually and object

Comment: `map()` takes each element (horse) of the array (horses) and passes it to the function (in this case it's a Component, common practice). It looks like you meant to use map inside of the SearchPage component. You don't need map here as you are passing the whole array to SearchPage anyway

Also you should make sure that the `window.horseData` is ready before the App initialises. And that it is actually an array []

Comment: Please provide example data, an [mre]. Where does the `N` come from in the error?

Comment: @AmanSadhwani Nothing is wrong with horseDataJson - it is in correct JSON format

Comment: make sure wherever you are calling `map` fn, it is called on an **array**.

Comment: @0stone0 I have no idea where N comes from

Comment: I don't think the error is from the posted code. It;s probably originating from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

If horseDataJSON variable is a JSON format, you need to parse it with

```
const parsedHorseData = JSON.parse(horseDataJSON)
```

So you can apply array method on it.

Comment: "So you can apply array method on it." - how would i make use of an array in the above component?

Comment: Would you please provide example of horseDataJSON?

Comment: Example provided in original post now